# Proxy Request with Minimal API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

So, I'm being forced into creating a gateway by the fact [that an API I want to consume in my Blazor WASM app doesn't play nicely with CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65761996/4700841).

So I want to create the quickest, laziest gateway API I can. This is categorically not going to be used for production code so I don't care about security or anything of the sort.

The shortest I've been able to come up with so far is:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
       .AddEnvironmentVariables();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
                 {
                     options.AddPolicy(name: "cors",
                                       policy =>
                                       {
                                           policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
                                       });
                 });


var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors("cors");

app.MapGet("/discos-proxy/{*discosRoute}", async (string discosRoute, HttpContext context) =>
                                           {
                                               HttpClient    client  = new();
                                               client.BaseAddress                         = new(app.Configuration.GetSection("DiscosOptions:DiscosApiUrl").Value);
                                               Console.WriteLine(context.Request.Headers.Authorization);
                                               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new("bearer", context.Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString().Split(' ')[1]);
                                               HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(discosRoute);
                                               res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                                               Stream             contentStream = await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                                               using StreamReader reader        = new(contentStream);
                                               string             content       = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                                               return content;
                                           });

app.Run();
```

I tried returning just the `HttpResponseMessage` directly but that doesn't seem to pull the content through.

---

So there are some obvious issues with this:

- If there's an error on the request, it'll 500
- It doesn't preserve any response headers (particularly important given the API I'm proxying here has a rate limiter)
- Many more

So am I missing a trick here or is there really no simple way to just proxy a request using these minimal APIs?

Comment: did you tried creating API gateway with Ocelot . https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though the suggestion from @CodingMytra in the comments was the easiest solution.

To create this gateway with ocelot I need to install the `Ocelot` package from Nuget and then have the following in my `Program.cs`.

```cs
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
       .AddJsonFile("ocelot.json")
       .AddEnvironmentVariables();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
                 {
                     options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                                       builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                                         .AllowAnyMethod()
                                                         .AllowAnyHeader());
                 });


builder.Services.AddOcelot();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

await app.UseOcelot();

await app.RunAsync();
```

It goes without saying that the very free CORS policy in this example should be tightened to suit your use case.

Essentially, I've just added CORS options (with `.UseCors(...)` and `.AddCors(...)`), and Ocelot options (with `.AddOcelot()` and `.UseOcelot()`).

Then, in my `ocelot.json`:

```json
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "discosweb.esoc.esa.int",
          "Port": 443
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5002/"
  }
}
```

This configuration takes every get request sent to the gateway and reroutes it to the downstream host (and prepends `/api/` to the path).